# Extracting text from script tag in Python

Tags: python, parsing, text, beautifulsoup, extract

I'm trying to extract the text inside a script tag (fig.1 below).

I used this code to extract the script part:
**script_blocks = soup.find_all('script type', {'type': 'text/javascript'})**
[image: fig.1]

What I need now is to extract the **yellow highlighted text above**. I already tried some approaches but but didn't work or return empty. Anyone can help? Below is the code I used till now. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: please don't post pics of code. Use the code tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re` module to extract the information from `<script>` tag:

```
import re
import requests

url = 'https://www.radiopopular.pt/produto/consola-ps4-500gb-fifa-21'

html_doc = requests.get(url).text

id_ = re.search(r"rp\.body\.product\.id = '(.*?)'", html_doc).group(1)
sa = re.search(r"rp\.body\.product\.sa = '(.*?)'", html_doc).group(1)
ean = re.search(r"rp\.body\.product\.ean = '(.*?)'", html_doc).group(1)
sef = re.search(r"rp\.body\.product\.sef = '(.*?)'", html_doc).group(1)

print(id_)
print(sa)
print(ean)
print(sef)
```

Prints:

```
80057
1289907
0711719828129
consola-ps4-500gb-fifa-21
```